# Ionic4: An error is output screen does not appear in the InAppBrowser

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to output a browser when starting ionic using InAppBrowser, but an error is output and nothing is displayed on the display screen as a white page.
Why?

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { InAppBrowser} from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx'; //add

@NgModule({
 (ellipsis)
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    InAppBrowser // add
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**home.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';　// add

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private inAppBrowser: InAppBrowser) {} // add

  ngOnInit() {
    const browser = this.inAppBrowser.create('https://www.google.com', '_blank', { location: 'no', zoom: 'no'});
  }
}
```

**error:**

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HomePage -> InAppBrowser]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HomePage -> InAppBrowser]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InAppBrowser!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HomePage -> InAppBrowser]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HomePage -> InAppBrowser]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InAppBrowser!
   (ellipsis)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ionic 4 uses lazy loading which means that every page has a `.module.ts` file as well.

There is a providers section inside that which you need to put the `InAppBrowser` reference.

In your example it looks like you're trying to use it in `home.page.ts` so that means look for `home.module.ts`, which looks something like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomePage } from './home.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

And needs to be updated to something like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { InAppBrowser} from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx'; //add

import { HomePage } from './home.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [
    InAppBrowser // add
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

You can find this information in the future by looking at the main page of the Ionic Native documentation. It's confusing because each individual plugin just assumes you know about this page:

- [Community Plugins - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/overview#angular)

Comment: thank you for your answer.

Equivalent code has been added to the module.ts file.
Probably this is a provider error, but I don't know how to import.
Would you please teach me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Pleease add *InAppBrowser* in providers in `module.ts` file

Comment: thank you for your answer.

I would appreciate it if you could explain in more detail.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may try service providers

```
import {ServiceProvider} from '../../providers/service-provider';
 providers: [
        ServiceProvider,
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
    ]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.
I tried to add the code, but “Module not found.” Is displayed.
To add this
`ionic g provider service-provider`

Can I add it by running

Thank you.

Comment: @TKeita..Have you imported StatusBar,
    SplashScreen, in your app.module.ts??

Comment: thank you for your answer.

Both are imported.
'
ServiceProvider,
         {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
'
If this 'IonicErrorHandler' was not found, an error was output.
`import {IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy, IonicErrorHandler} from '@ ionic / angular`
When this was added, "Module not found" was displayed. Do you have anything to add?